# Redirecting Url to Local Host

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

My website items has pictures which were external links. Now I have bought all the images for those item picture and place into my directory inside a picture folder. I would like to know instead of changing individual item picture link is there a way to redirect old item link to new directory. Example

Old Link:
http://www.something.com/images/item_images/item28.jpg

New Directory Name:
images/item_images

I would like to capture "something.com" and change it with my own website link. like "mywebsite.com/rest_of_the_link". How can I achieve this?

Comment: Note that we encourage readers to show us what they have found in their research, and/or what code they have. Would you be able to edit your question with that material?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this using .htacces file in root directory, seee:

https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/htaccess_redirect

http://www.htaccessredirect.net

Or maby using virtual host in apache if you have access to ssh console.

https:// httpd.apache.org /docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html